# Create a new variable in dataframe for multiple subgroups, depending on multiple conditions in a third variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains a column for a subject id, one column that contains a date and a third column that contains comments ('usable'/'unusable'/'questionable'). An example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'Date':[20191219,
                           20191219,
                           20191220,
                           20191220,
                           20191219,
                           20191219,
                           20191219],
                           'Notes':['usable','usable','unusable','questionable','usable','usable','unusable']})
```

Which gives you:

```
   ID      Date         Notes
0   1  20191219        usable
1   1  20191219        usable
2   1  20191220      unusable
3   1  20191220  questionable
4   2  20191219        usable
5   2  20191219        usable
6   2  20191219      unusable
```

For each subject and for each respective date I want to check if the string 'questionable' or 'unusable' appears in the Notes column. If this is the case I want to add the value 'check' to a third column for all rows corresponding to that date. The output should look like this:

```
   ID      Date         Notes Comment
0   1  20191219        usable  usable
1   1  20191219        usable  usable
2   1  20191220      unusable   check
3   1  20191220  questionable   check
4   2  20191219        usable   check
5   2  20191219        usable   check
6   2  20191219      unusable   check
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) + `df.groupby()` with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `any` for each group to create a conditional column, followed by [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
c=(df['Notes'].isin(['unusable','questionable'])
                 .groupby([df['ID'],df['Date']]).transform('any'))
df['Comment']=np.where(c,'check',df['Notes'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   ID      Date         Notes Comment
0   1  20191219        usable  usable
1   1  20191219        usable  usable
2   1  20191220      unusable   check
3   1  20191220  questionable   check
4   2  20191219        usable   check
5   2  20191219        usable   check
6   2  20191219      unusable   check
```